# extracting XML from HTML?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

[Reference page](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=NS044283%5BGR%5D&dispmax=200&report=xml)

The XML is embedded under the `<pre>` tag of the returned HTML page.
I can extract the contents of the `<pre>` tag, but I am unable to convert this to XML correctly.
I tried using the `to_xml` method of the NodeSet class, but it seems that the line endings (`\n`) are messing up the parsing.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
url = "http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=NS044283[GR]&dispmax=200&report=xml"
doc = Nokogiri::XML(open(url))
pre = doc.xpath('//pre')
xml = pre.to_xml
contents = Nokogiri::XML(xml)
articles = contents.xpath('\\PubmedArticle')
(article = [])
```

Comment: `to_xml` tells Nokogiri to convert the content of the node into XML, causing it to reencode the `<`, `>` and other "illegal" characters, which you then have to decode. Use `text` and Nokogiri will decode the encoded characters, which you can then parse as XML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're going to use Nokogiri to parse it anyway, just call `content` instead of `to_xml`:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
url = "http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=NS044283[GR]&dispmax=200&report=xml"
doc = Nokogiri::XML(open(url))
pre = doc.xpath('//pre')
xml = "<root>" + pre.text + "</root>"
contents = Nokogiri::XML(xml)
articles = contents.css('PubmedArticle')
puts contents.css('ArticleTitle').map{|x| x.content}.count   
=> 25
```

Comment: Instead of `pre.first.content`, convert using `pre.text`. It should be the same result. `pre.text.size => 387471` or `pre.first.content.size => 387471`

Comment: Yep, got same result with `#text`

Comment: `articles.count or .size` only gives me `1`. There should be 20+, corresponding to the number of `<PubmedArticle>` tags. Am I missing something? Awesome responses btw!

Comment: It's not actually valid XML. there needs to be a root XML element. Updated above.

Comment: It's definitely not valid XML or HTML. See my answer/comment.

Comment: This is an excellent example of the "heckish" XML out there. While XML is supposed to enforce correctness and compliance with a standard, people are so "creative" they can mess it up. We have to analyze their mess, and patch their output, just to reuse it. It's easy to tell the authors of this data never tried reloading their output as a sanity check that they're doing their job right. Sigh....

Answer (score 1):

The document being retrieved isn't valid XML or HTML. Shame on those who created it.

Here's the first 200 characters, showing some confusion on their part:

```
require 'open-uri'
url = "http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=NS044283[GR]&dispmax=200&report=xml"
puts open(url).read[0..200]
```

which returns:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<pre>
&lt;PubmedArticle&gt;
    &lt;Medl
```

Luckily, or, maybe determinedly, Nokogiri works around that by being somewhat lenient with malformed HTML.

Answer (score -1):

The embedded XML is not valid (HTML-escaped). Try to unescape it

```
...
xml = CGI.unescapeHTML(pre.to_xml) # or CGI.unescapeHTML(pre.to_s)
...
```

Comment: It's not necessary to use `CGI.unescapeHTML`. Instead, use `pre.text` and Nokogiri will decode the entities and turn them back into regular tags. For instance: `pre.text[0..50] => 
"\n<PubmedArticle>\n    <MedlineCitation Owner=\"NLM\" S"`